# Spark Streaming Application getting failed

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have deployed 3 node Spark-1.5.0 Cluster.

I created one Spark Streaming application with multiple Broadcast Variables, which is working fine.

But due to some server load or some other applications, my streaming batches are getting delayed.

[image]

Which leads to a pending queue processes.

[image]

Sometime its able to process all pending batches but sometime it gets stuck. and when i click on particular batch it gives me broadcast failure error.

[image]

This is my full error log

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 71938.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 71938.0 (TID 478900, 192.168.1.19): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_2_piece0 of broadcast_2
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1178)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at com.bdbizviz.smb.util.DataProcessing$$anonfun$processStreaming$3.apply(DataProcessing.scala:75)
    at com.bdbizviz.smb.util.DataProcessing$$anonfun$processStreaming$3.apply(DataProcessing.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.util.CountingIterator.next(CountingIterator.scala:16)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:106)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.next(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.GroupingBatchBuilder.foreach(GroupingBatchBuilder.scala:31)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:154)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:138)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:139)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:109)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:138)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:34)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming.DStreamFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DStreamFunctions.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_2_piece0 of broadcast_2
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1175)
    ... 31 more

Driver stacktrace:
```

I also got 2 more error before this exception.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1612)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.ThrowableSerializationWrapper.readObject(TaskEndReason.scala:163)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1017)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1893)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:72)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$3$$anonfun$run$2.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:105)
```

And

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: ArrayBuffer(kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException, org.apache.spark.SparkException: Couldn't find leader offsets for Set([Test1,4], [Test2,1],[Test2,3], [Test3,4], [Test4,1], [Test2,3], [Test5,2], [Test2,0], [Test1,5], [Test2,5], [Test2,2]))
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.latestLeaderOffsets(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:123)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.DirectKafkaInputDStream.compute(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:40)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
         at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FilteredDStream.compute(FilteredDStream.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:350)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:349)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:399)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:342)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:35)
```

Comment: Given the broadcast and kafka kind of error, it maybe some connection problem. Maybe one of your nodes has some issues communicating with the rest

Comment: @Kaushal - Did you resolve this issue? i am having a similar case

Comment: Yes, Check your cluster, Is it properly communicating or not?